# Dangers of using Tor snowflake?

Tags: tor

The Tor project has recently released a browser extension called [snowflake](https://snowflake.torproject.org/) which allows users in countries with heavy censorship to access websites which would otherwise be blocked using the connections of volunteers as proxies. They have stated -

> There is no need to worry about which websites people are accessing through your proxy. Their visible browsing IP address will match their Tor exit node, not yours.

Which clears up one worry that most people would have with volunteering for such a project.

But are there any dangers for allowing your system to act as such a proxy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake uses WebRTC. If you are also using a VPN, enabling WebRTC can expose your real public IP behind a VPN.

This varies with Browser and VPN.

Comment: the STUN request bug has been patched AFAIK. Correct me if I'm wrong